# Quick questions about the definition for Indecomposable group?

Tags: group-theory, definition

The definition of an indecomposable group is defined as a group $G$ that can not be written as a direct product of its proper normal subgroups. In some places i seen on the internet and books, the last part of the definition states that it cannot be written as a direct product of its proper subgroups.  I am just wondering which one should I accept as the correct definition.  Also does the definition imply that every element of $G$ can not be written as the direct product of some pair of its proper subgroups/normal subgroups or every elements of $G$ can not be written as the direct product of every pair of its proper subgroups/normal subgroups.  As an example:

The classic example is that of $S_3.$

The subgroups of $S_3$ are $\{e,\{e,(12)\},\{e,(13)\},\{e,(23)\},\{e,(123)\},\{e,(123), (132)\}.$ $\{e,\{e,(12)\},\{e,(13)\},\{e,(23)\},\{e,(123)\}$ are not normal subgroups and $\{e,(123), (132)\}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3.$ But what happens when a group $G$ has more than two normal subgroups and more than two non normal subgroups. We can have the case where if I choose two normal subgroups, than $G$ can be written as a direct product.  But if I choose one noraml subgroup and one non normal subgroups, then it fails the definition.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Neither of those is technically correct. It should be "as a direct product of two proper (normal) subgroups". The normal is in paranthesis, because the presense of the word does not actually change the definition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft according to the text i am using, the definition of indecomposable group is:  "A group $G$ is said to be $\textbf{indecomposable}$ if it is $\textit{not}$ the direct product of two of its proper normal subgroups."  In some places, it simply says proper subgroups.  At planetmath webpage, it says that it is not the internal direct product.

Comment: And as I said, the word "normal" does not ctually change anything (you should show this). Similarly, internal or external does not change anything, except the viewpoint.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft i don't understand why the word "normal" does not change anything?  My undersstanding for a group to be written as pair of direct product of groups, both groups in the pair have to be normal subgroups.  Also, does the definition imply that some element of a group can not be written as direct product of a pair of normal proper subgroups.  I am getting tripped up by the implicit quantifiers.

Comment: The word "normal" changes nothing, because as you say, the subgroups will automatically be normal anyway. I am not sure what you mean by the question about elements. The term "direct product" is not applicable to elements of a group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the theorem in my text about direct product of groups is that:  "If $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $G=MN$ and $M\cap N=\langle e \rangle$ then $G=M\times N.$"  The condition for $G=MN$ means that elements of $G$ is written as a product of an element from $M$ and an element from $N.$  For the cayley table of $S_3$ it seems that $\{e,(123)\}$ and $\{e,(132)\}$ can serve as $M$ and $N$ respectively.  But but, then we run into problems if say $M=\{e,(12)\}$ and $N=\{e,(123)\}.$

Comment: The two subsets you have there are not subgroups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft oh right, I think it should be $M=\{e,(12)$ and $N=\{e,(123), (132)\}.$  But what happens if a group $G$ has more than two proper normal subgroups and more than two proper non normal subgroups.  What happens in such case?  Does one has to go try out every possible pair?

Comment: Now we are getting into question of how to determine if a group is indecomposable it seems, which is only tangentially related to the question about the definition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft in the definition for indecomposable group, is it saying that for a group $G$ to be indecomposable, that it can not be wrttien as a direct product of two of its proper normal subgroups.  My understanding it that for finite groups, the definition for external and internal direct product conincide.  There seems to be something subtle that I am having trouble understanding about the definition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I edit my post to accurately reflect what I am confused about from the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say $G$ is an internal direct product of $N_1$ and $N_2$ if and only if three things happen:

1. $N_1\triangleleft G$ and $N_2\triangleleft G$; (in particular they are subgroups of $G$); **and**
2. $G=N_1N_2$; **and**
3. $N_1\cap N_2=\{e\}$.

You need all three to say $G$ is the (internal) direct product of $M$ and $N$. If all three happens, and **only** if all three things happen, we write $G=N_1\times N_2$.

A group $G$ is **decomposable** if and only if there exist nontrivial normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ of $G$ such that $G=N_1\times N_2$ (internal direct product).

But note that if $G=N_1\times N_2$, then this requires $N_1\triangleleft G$, $N_2\triangleleft G$, $G=N_1N_2$, and $N_1\cap N_2=\{e\}$, so we may *conclude* that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are normal. Thus, we can just say:

> $G$ is **decomposable** if and only if there exist nontrivial subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ of $G$ such that $G=N_1\times N_2$.

Because "$G=N_1\times N_2$" implies $N_1\triangleleft G$ and $N_2\triangleleft G$. So to address the extensive back-and-forth in comments: it doesn't matter if you define "decomposable" specifying the subgroups must be normal or not, in either case you have the subgroups are normal.

Second:  a group $G$ is **indecomposable** if and only if it is not decomposable. Negating the definition gives:

> A group $G$ is **indecomposable** if and only if there do not exist nontrivial subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ of $G$ such that $G=N_1\times N_2$.

Or

> A group $G$ is **indecomposable** if and only if there do not exist nontrivial normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ of $G$ such that $G=N_1\times N_2$.

Or

> A group $G$ is **indecomposable** if and only if for any nontrivial normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ of $G$, either $G\neq N_1N_2$ or $N_1\cap N_2\neq\{e\}$.

Or

> A group $G$ is **indecomposable** if and only if for any subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ of $G$, at least one of the following happens:
>
> 1. $N_1=\{e\}$ or $N_2=\{e\}$ (they are not nontrivial); or
> 2. $N_1$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$, or $N_2$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$; or
> 3. $N_1\cap N_2\neq\{e\}$; or
> 4. $N_1N_2\neq G$.

What does this have to do with $G$ having "more than two normal subgroups" or "more than two non-normal subgroups"? It just means you have more pairs to check. If $G$ has only one nontrivial normal subgroup, then either 1 or 3 fails, so there is nothing to do. If it has more than one nontrivial normal subgroup, then you need to check more things. The non-normal subgroups are irrelevant to testing indecomposability, even though the definition need not explicitly mention the two subgrups must be normal, because for $G$ to be decomposable you need two  nontrivial normal subgroups with additional properties, regardless of whether you said "normal" or not in the definition.

Comment: I did some digging from various abstract algebra/group theory texts.  It seems that the easiest criteria to check for whether a group $G$ is indecomposable and if that group $G$ has more than say two non trivial subgroups, is if i cab find two subgroups of that group and they have non trivial intersection.  Am I correct in my impression?

Comment: @Seth: That's not a "criteria". That's a sufficient condition.

Comment: I thought your list of 4 conditions are consider criterias.  Okay, sufficient conditions, then.  Thank you for the detail write up.

Comment: @Seth A criterion/criteria is "a principle or standard by which something may be judged or decided." The condition does not "decide" because it can fail to be met in an indecomposable group.

Comment: could you give me a classic example, or should i just remember the four conditions you list can be consider sufficient conditions, where if a group can be shown to satisfy any one of them, then that group is consider to be indecomposable.

Comment: @Seth A classic example of *what*? The easiest thing to remember is what it means to be **decomposable**, and then take the negation of that.

Comment: The four condition I gave, taken together, are in fact a criterion. The one you give (verify that any two nontrivial normal subgroups have nontrivial intersection) is a sufficient condition, but not a criterion, since a group may have satisfy that there are nontrivial normal subgroups with trivial intersection, and yet be indecomposable.

Comment: if a group is of large order, then there are not really an easy way to check for those each one of the four sufficient conditions you listed.  If I read a book in group theory, would there are theorems that allow me to check for whether a group is decomposable.  I am about to learn about burnside's theorem, composition series, orbit stablizer theorem and the sylow theorems.

Comment: @Seth: "If I read a book in group theory, would there are[sic] theorems that allow me to check for whether a group is decomposable[?]" There's an easy way to find out: grab a book and look it up in the index. Books are weird that way.

Comment: I am hoping you would tell me if I go to a certain topic, I should pay attention to certain things that will  help me with my question.  You are someone who studies group theory, and you have better intuituion than someone like me who is a beginner.

Comment: @Seth What you are hoping is that I look through books and tell you where to look, so that you don't have to spend your time searching. You'll have to pay me to engage my time in doing work for you.

Comment: no worries.  Again thank you for the write up